# Why, in "they help her", is "her" a direct object?

Tags: grammar

Can anybody explain why, in the sentence "they helped her", is *her* a direct object, even though we ask a question as if it's an indirect object "to whom?"

Comment: You ask "Whom?" in English. You probably ask "To whom?" in Slavic languages, which is why you are confused.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in concluding that, if English were a language that actually used the rules it prints in grammar books, then, yes, it would be an *indirect object*.

You can still see the left-over indirect object if you change the sentence a little.  If you were to say, "They gave help to her", you can see the indirect object still left over in our English ("*to* her").  We would not say, "They gave help her."

However, sadly, if you change the word order a little you can make the English act as if it has a direct object:  "They gave her help" = "They gave help to her."

Finally, note that many of the distinctions in other languages that are shown by cases (nominative, genitive, dative, accusative, etc) have fallen away in English. And our language is mostly driven by its prepositions (to/for/on/with, etc.)

So, to answer your question: "They help her" is a short cut way of saying "they give help to her."  You are right that it should be a I.O.  But most English speakers don't know what an indirect object is anymore.

Comment: Just because "They help her" and "They give help to her" have the same meaning doesn't necessarily mean that "her" should have the same grammatical function in both sentences. By this logic, in the two sentences "They feed her" and "They put food on her plate", should "her" have the same grammatical function?

Answer (score 1):

The direct object of the verb is the thing/person upon which/whom the action of the verb is done; the person or thing that receives the action of the verb,

She is being helped - she receives the help.